# Cache Lookup Properties in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, etl, azure-data-factory

I have a requirement where in I have a source file containing the Table Name(s) in Mapping Data Flow. Based on the Table Name in the file - there needs to be a dynamic query where column metadata, along with some other properties is retrieved from the data dictionary tables and inserted into a different sink table. The table name from the file would be used as a where condition filter.

Since there can be multiple tables listed in the input file (lets assume its a csv with only one column containing the table names), if we decide to use a cache sink for the file :

1. Is it possible to use the results of that cached sink in the Source transformation query in the same mapping data flow - as a lookup (from where the column metadata is being retrieved) and if Yes, how
2. What would be the best way to restrict data from the metadata table query based on this table name
3. Though of alternatively achieving this with a pipeline using For Each passing the table name as parameter to data flow, but in this case if there are 100 tables in the file, there would be 100 iterations and 100 times the cluster would need to be spun up. Please advise if this is wronf or there are better ways to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use option 3. Loop through the table names and pass each in as a parameter to the data flow to set the table name in the dataset.

ADF handles the cluster creation and teardown. All you have to worry about is whether you want to execute each sequentially or in parallel and how many. There are concurrency limits in ADF, so you should consider a batch count of 20 if you run in parallel.

Comment: 1) Sequential is needed cause the input entries are dependent on the max key of the target table. Is there anyway to run this parallel
2) With option 3 - will the cluster not spin up 100 times for 100 tables and will this not add a overhead of warming up the cluster so many times. Further from the cost perspective is it suggested

Comment: Set a small TTL value on the Azure IR and the cluster will be available in each subsequent execution in about 1.5 mins. We're working on a feature to improve upon Databrick's warm pool implementation to cut that down to under 1 min.